# Question about setting up Google Analytics with Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google, google-analytics

At the bottom of vendor profile, there is an text box for you to insert your GA code.

[image]

Question: what does this do? What kind of stats am I expected to see in Google Analytics? I don't have the luxury of trial and error at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is an amazingly helpful tool. I would suggest reading for the specifics on their site if you haven't already, but on top of that, I did you one better: I took some screenshots of the dashboard and report table of my own Analytics page, to give you an idea of how awesome Analytics is. You can view it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc1Ab.jpg

The dashboard, and all reports, are fully customizable, and they tell you exactly what is going on with... well, your whole site, really.

There's nothing another stat-tracking software can tell you that Google Analytics can not.